# TSQL query difference between h:mm and H:mm in format command

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, format

I would imagine this would have been asked at some point in time, but I can't find it.

I currently use Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and in the Management Studio I run the following query:

```
SELECT 
   DATEADD(hh, -4, DATEADD(s, 1396625291613/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00')) [raw date]
  ,format(dateadd(hh, - 4, dateadd(s, 1396625291613 / 1000, '1970-01-01 00:00:00')), 'M/d/yy h:mm tt') [h:mm]
  ,format(dateadd(hh, - 4, dateadd(s, 1396625291613 / 1000, '1970-01-01 00:00:00')), 'M/d/yy H:MM tt') [H:MM]
```

The results I get are:

```
2014-04-04 11:28:11.000
4/4/14 11:28 AM
4/4/14 11:04 AM
```

The question is why is this returning two different times when formatting as h:mm vs H:MM.  One is 11:28 and the other is 11:04.

I've looked on sites like www.epochconverter.com and found that the lower case is correct, but why is upper case shaving 24 minutes off in this case.  When I do a whole list of epoch conversion dates I find it isn't consistent in the differences.

As a back story, I store epoch values in a database for things like a create stamp or last update stamp, that sort of thing.

Thanks.

Comment: [`mm` is minute, `MM` is month](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).  `h` is 12-hour hour, `H` is 24-hour hour.  `H:MM` is taking the 24-hour Hour vcalue and the 2-digit month value giving you `"11:04"`

Comment: ok now I feel stupid.  Thanks though :)

Comment: No worries - I can never remember which is which and have to try it or read the docs.

Comment: This is why you should not use those shortcuts. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations